# Google Compute Engine Cent OS change hostname

Tags: centos, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Title says it all really - I want to change the hostname of a Google Compute Engine Cent OS instance.

I have tried the normal method...

- in `/etc/sysconfig/network` set `HOSTNAME=my.new.hostname`
- in `/etc/hosts` set `127.0.1.1  my.new.hostname`
- reboot

I have tried setting a `hostname` key/value pair in the `Custom metadata` of the `Compute Engine` `VM Instance` admin page.

Nothing sticks. Seems to use the instance name as hostname.

Comment: What is the value in /etc/hostname?

Comment: @Peter - there is no `/etc/hostname` file

Comment: @Peter `/etc/hostname` will be used in RHEL 7, but RHEL 6 uses `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata

Answer (score 2):

By default there is a start up script which sets the hostname according to the metadata of that instance.
See: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/tree/master/google-startup-scripts

```
Sets the hostname from the metadata server via DHCP exit hooks.
```

Comment: I'm getting 404 page. And is there a way to change that? I'd like that the hostname to be a FQDN hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [hostname(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) ?

> Hostname is the program that is used to either set or display the current host, domain or node name of the system. These names are used by many of the networking programs to identify the machine.

```
hostname
xyzzy.example.com

hostname plugh.example.com

hostname
plugh.example.com
```

Comment: I did try that, and it works until the machine is rebooted :(

Answer (score 0):

Change hostname in Google Compute Engine (Cent OS)

Step 1

```
# nano /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=my.new.hostname
```

Step 2: Create crontab auto set Hostname

```
# crontab -e
@reboot hostname="my.new.hostname"; sed -i "s/.*Google.*//" /etc/hosts; hostname "$hostname"
```

Step 3

```
# reboot
```

Step 4: Add below

```
# nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    my.new.hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to have a permanent hostname (for CentOS 6 & 7):

```sh
# cd /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/
# ls
azure-cloud.sh
# touch update-hostname.sh
# nano update-hostname.sh # or you can use vi
# cat update-hostname.sh 
hostname my.fqdndomain.com
# chmod a+x update-hostname.sh
```